# Using codeship to pull docker images from Github Conatiner Registry using the dockercfg file

Tags: devops, github-actions, docker-registry, codeship

apologies if this has been asked before.
I have been going through the documentation for codeship to see if I can  pull an image for docker from a private github container registry (GHCR) when I am automating my build process.
The documentation specifies docker registries but nothing for the GHCR.
Has anyone used  Codeship to pull docker images from the GHCR?
The documentation specifies  that the most common way authenticate with image registries is to provide your account credentials via an encrypted dockercfg file. The example is as follows:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "your_auth_string",
            "email": "your_email"
        }
    }
}
```

This file will later be encrypted as per the instructions in the docs which can be found [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-codeship/latest/pro-builds-and-configuration/image-registries)

I was wondering if anyone has used this for GHCR, and if they have my question is whether one can simply replace the URL with the GHCR URL and pass it the email and personal access token used to access the packages or in this case images in the GHCR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after opening a ticket with Codeship and explaining to them what I was trying to do I got told the following:

"I don't think that we don't officially support the GitHub Container Registry; but, checking with the team on that. You likely can get it to work if it operates in a similar manner as the registries listed in the [documentation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-codeship/latest/pro-builds-and-configuration/image-registries)."

I then tried it and it worked as expected. I also later received an email saying
"The engineering team confirmed that this method should work for you. We are going to update our documentation soon with a proper guide".

In my case I had to create a credentials.env file, add the repository credentials and GHCR url instead of the method mentioned in the question to generate the dockercfg file since I am doing this on Mac OS because the newer versions of Docker have changed to store credentials in the macOS keychain rather than in a configuration file. The instructions can be found [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-codeship/latest/pro-builds-and-configuration/image-registries#_docker_credentials_on_mac_osx)

I hope this is useful to whoever comes across this in future until they have updated the documentation but as of 28th of January 2021, it has not yet been updated.